# 3D Drag and Shoot mechanic(like in angry birds) not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a 3D golf game where one of the mechanics of the game is to drag your mouse and release to make it go the other way. It's similar to when you play Angry Birds, where you have to drag your character and release to go the other way. When I drag the ball back and release it goes in the opposite direction but it doesn't go in the air even when I drag my mouse to a lower y-value. My code is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class dragnshoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private bool is_shoot;
    // true or false if the ball is shoot
    private Vector3 mouse_press_downpos;
    // stores the mouse position when pressed down(point in 3d space)
    private Vector3 mouse_release_pos;
    // release position(a point)
    private Vector3 force;
    // stores the vector of the force
    private Rigidbody rigbod;
    private Vector3 forceVector;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rigbod = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    // how to make the force go up in the air
    void Update()
    {
        // if is_shoot is true, then the ball is already shoot, then wait for it to stop moving.
        // after it has stopped moving, we can shoot again.
        if(is_shoot && rigbod.velocity.magnitude < 0.1f)
        {
            is_shoot = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        mouse_press_downpos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.z, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // could use input key: press a key to make it go in y direction
        mouse_release_pos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.z, Input.mousePosition.y);
        // debug returns the current value of that variable
        Debug.Log("mouse_release_pos: " + mouse_release_pos);
        Debug.Log("mouse_release_pos: " + mouse_release_pos); 
        Vector3 force = mouse_release_pos-mouse_press_downpos;
        Shoot(force);
    }

    private float force_multiplier = 5;
    
    void Shoot(Vector3 force){
        if (is_shoot) return;
        
        Vector3 forcevector = new Vector3(force.x, force.y, force.z);
        forceVector *= -1;
        Debug.Log("forceVector: " + forceVector);
        // add the opposite force times the force multiplier to the rigid body
        rigbod.AddForce(forcevector*-force_multiplier);
        is_shoot = true;
    }



}
```

Comment: MousePosition always has a 0-value z vector. Additionally, you're putting Input.mousePosition.z into the y value of your new vectors. This is likely causing some confusion.

Comment: @ErikOverflow might be valid if the app is e.g. in top-down view ... what is worth mentioning though: the mouse position is in **pixel space** while `Rigidbody` works in world space - currently the applied force is completely dependent on the screen/player  resolution ...

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a game a while back ago that also used an Angry-Birds-style pull-back mechanic. So I can give you some tips that helped me and point out some things your program does less than optimal, and hopefully one of my answers will solve your problem.

1. I used `StartPoint = Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` and `CurrentPoint = Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` to measure the starting and ending positions of the mouse as I found this way to work better than how you did it  `mouse_press_downpos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.z, Input.mousePosition.y);`
2. In this line  `mouse_press_downpos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.z, Input.mousePosition.y);` you accidentally entered the z position of the mouse to the y-axis and vice-versa. I would again suggest you use my method of measuring mouse location as it's much cleaner.
3. In your Shoot function you assigned the 'ForceVector' the 'Force' value, then you multiplied it by -1, and then did it again in the 'addForce' line. Completely unnecessary and very confusing. just calculate it like: `startPos-EndPos`, which should give you the right direction no matter what.
4. I found that using `rb.AddForce(Force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);` instead of `rb.AddForce(Force);` worked much smoother and gave me the exact effect I wanted.

Hope I helped, Goodluck(;